# What is the reason for some very popular sites like Reddit use ugly User Interface?

Tags: interface

I got a project to build a website like Reddit. My client need a very attractive modern look interface.

But he asked that why Reddit website look so ugly? IS there any UI /UX reason for it?

I did not have a answer when he asking. I said I will do a research and let you know. But still I could not find the reson for it...

Comment: Specifically in Reddit's case, the 'crappy' UI does allow for more threads to be stacked which is what most users need because they browse a LOT of different threads per session. If you look at the custom css templates that some subreddits use, you'll see that Reddit's structure by essence is not horrid, the default is just plain.

Answer (score 0):

Because it works and there is no real competitor to make Reddit more attractive.

And for the record, reddit's user experience - at least for a novice user - is beyond horrific, and almost reduced me to tears.